# Remove HTML less than greater than tag in some cases

Tags: java, html

Expression which will remove less than `<` and greater than `>` tags but if Span tag is there then I need to keep as it is.Following is my input and expected output.

input

```
<table><tr>
<td>abc <span class="abc">Test</span>
thank you <JPG>Spring5<span class='Search'>One</span>
```

Output

```
table tr
td abc <span class="abc">Test</span>
thank you JPG Spring5<span class='Search'>One</span>
```

Comment: Check out some [Regex](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm).

Comment: @JqueryLearner I need to remove html less than and greater character if it is present in input. but for span tag of less then and greater symbol I need to keep as it is. I have mentioned input and expected output.

Comment: This sounds like it might be [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve by using this technique?

Answer (score 2):

```
</?span[^>]*>|[^<>]
```